# How to create new NSMutableArrays on the fly

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I want to create some `NSMutableArray`s. The numbers of arrays I want to create depends on another variable.  Since I don't know how many arrays will be created, can I create these arrays on the fly and assign the array name with a variable?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create `NSMutableArray`s on the fly; you just have to store them within a dynamically expandable data structure. I suggest either storing them within their own `NSMutableArray` or, if it's absolutely necessary for you to associate each with its own variable, you can store the arrays within an `NSMutableDictionary`.